# C# PivotItem doesn't have any content

Tags: c#, windows, pivot, universal

I am building a windows universal app in Visual Studio 2015 and i have a strange problem with pivot.

This is my MainPage.xaml file :

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Pivot x:Name="PivotMainPageStations"></Pivot>
        </Grid>       
    </ScrollViewer>
```

This is a function where i add PivotItems to my Pivot.

```
    private void ShowResults(Stations StationsObject)
    {           

        //clear items from PivotMainPageStations in case there are any left
        PivotMainPageStations.Items.Clear();

        //Iterating throught list of stations, creating a new user control of type StationUserControl 
        //and adding the StationUserControl to the pivot

        foreach (var item in StationsObject.stations)
        {

            StationUserControl station = new StationUserControl();
            station.MyStation = item;

            //Creating a new pivot item (pvtStation)
            PivotItem pvtStation = new PivotItem();

            pvtStation.Header = String.Format("{0} {1}", item.StationNumber, item.StationName);

            pvtStation.Content = station;

            PivotMainPageStations.Items.Add(pvtStation);

        }
    }
```

Here is my problem :

When Pivot already contains one (exclusively one) PivotItem and the function ShowResults gets called again, the new default selected PivotItem doesn't have any content. It has a header, but no content. This is strange, because it all works normal when Pivot contains 2 PivotItems and ShowResults gets called with same parameter as in the first case.

Has anyone ever had similar problem ? I have no idea what could be causing this.